# Spyder5 Monitor Calibration Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: display, monitor, color-management

I tried to get the Spyder5Express running under Ubuntu 14.04.
Installed is dispcalGUI and the Argyll_V1.7.0 software.

Unfortunately the device is neither detected in the GUI nor in the Terminal. I added myself to the colord group.

Terminal looks like this:

```
sudo dispcal -v -y l -q h -o TargetA

Setting up the instrument

dispcal: Error - new_disprd() failed with 'Instrument Access Failed'
```

`lsusb` generates:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0749:1000 EVer Electronics Corp. 

Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M500 Laser Mouse

Bus 005 Device 007: ID 085c:0500 ColorVision, Inc. 

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

The dispcalGUI does not find an Instrument. I can' t add a screenshot though

Any ideas?

Thank you
Sven

Comment: Sorry for the layout. Seemed to be fine before I posted the question...

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Any ideas so far?

Comment: Have you installed the latest dispcalGUI version? Because it's not long ago they added the Spyder5 support. Furthermore, once you start dispcalGUI, it should suggest you the built-in download of the right driver for the device. Did that happen?

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced this same issue with my new Spyder5 on Ubuntu 14.04. For the sake of completeness, (and for my own future self googling this :-), I'll add all issues I've ran into and their solution:

> **Problem: dispcalGUI does not detect the instrument at all**
>
> Solution: [Argyll CMS](http://argyllcms.com) needs to be downloaded and installed manually, as stated in the first step of the [dispcalGUI Quickstart Guide](http://dispcalgui.hoech.net/#quickstart). After installing, run dispcalGUI, select *File -> Locate Argyll CMS executables* and locate the bin folder of your Argyll CMS installation.
>
> **Problem: Calibrate & profile fails with *Error - new_disprd() failed with 'Instrument Access Failed'***
>
> Solution: Check if /etc/udev/rules.d/55-Argyll.rules exists. If not,
> copy it from the Argyll install directory (or downloaded package). It
> is in the folder usb/. Then reboot the system or at the very least,
> unplug the device and plug it back in again. More info can be found in
> the [Argyll installation
> manual](http://argyllcms.com/doc/Installing_Linux.html#udev1).
>
> **USB 2 / 3**
>
> Apparently there might be issues when using some devices on an USB 3 port.
> If possible, try switching it to an USB 2 port and see if this helps.
> In my case it was not necessary, the Spyder5 runs fine on my USB 3 port.
>
> **Last resort**
>
> If all else fails, you could run either Windows or OS X on a separate
> partition and do the calibration there using the vendor software. The
> resulting ICC profile is compatible across operating systems, so it is
> possible to import it to Linux. I haven't looked into this in detail as dispcalGUI seems to be working now for me.